# Help with preg_replace and special chars

Tags: php, preg-replace, special-characters, sanitization

I'm using the PDO class but I'm triying to remove all chars except...:

```
function cleaner($str){
    return preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9éàêïòé\,\.\']/',' ',trim($str));
}
```

As you can see, it's a simple function, but it removes all chars `éàêïòé`

example: **cleaner('$#$<<>-//La souris a été mangée par le chat ')** //returns

**La souris a t mang e par le chat** 
(The mouse has been eaten by the cat :) )

Any help will be appreciate

Comment: This happens because PHP's unicode support is broken.

Comment: Thanks for ur comment, so this means i gota wait for PHP 6??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$str = '$#$<<>-//La souris a été mangée par le chat ';
$str = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9éàêïòé\,\.\']/u',' ',trim($str));

$str = '$#$<<>-//La souris a été mangée par le chat ';
$str = preg_replace('/[^\p{L}\,\.\']/u',' ',trim($str));
```

Both the snippets worked for me, on PHP 5.3. The second regular expression is less restricted, and accepts all Unicode letters.

Comment: Thanks for ur help. I'm using Npp and it adds **ï»¿** to the file. I think those chars break the encoding.

Comment: @jartaud: Which PHP version are you using?

Comment: Are those characters added at the beginning of the file?

Comment: @kiamlaluno, sorry for the delay, I'm using PHP 5.3 and yes those chars are added at the biginning. Now i've setted the encoding to utf8.

Comment: I was thinking the editor was adding the BOM mark but, AFAIK, the characters used for the BOM should not be visible in the edited file.

Comment: @kiamlaluno, thanks again buddy. I opened the file with PHPDesigner and  I saw the BOM mark.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add /u pattern modifier to your pattern to turn on UTF-8 support in PCRE. This is assuming everything is in UTF-8 already.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php